# Deploying and running a war file

Tags: java, tomcat, jaxb, jersey, war

(Please see the code Code below) I am able to run it on Tomcat in the eclipse environment and it works as it should.
I have exported the following to a war file and created a Manifest.MF with:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.process.Test
```

When the code is ran in Eclipse the response from there server side is output to a console.

Now finally my question (Pardon my ignorance, I am fairly new to this):

**Once the war is deployed on my Tomcat server, how do I send a REST request or run the war and display the server response?**

What is the equivalent to :http://localhost:8080/rest/xml/list  on a live server?

Web.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>com.process.Test</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.process.Test</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Client side code:

```
import java.net.URI; 
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
//import com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;

public class Test 
{       
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Instead on using Apache Client 
    //used default Jersey client 
    //to send requests          
    ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
    Client client = Client.create(config);      
    String _package = "api.amebatv.com";
    WebResource service = client.resource(getBaseURI(_package));

    //runRequest(service,"indexpath");
    runRequest(service,"list");
}

/*
 * For testing purposes the base URI is :http://localhost:8080/package name
 * Will change to domain name for production code
 */
private static URI getBaseURI(String _package){
    return UriBuilder.fromUri(
            "http://localhost:8080/api.process.com").build();
}


private static void runRequest(WebResource service,String path){
    String response = service.path("rest/xml/"+path).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(String.class);
    System.out.println("Post Response :"+response);
}

}
```

Server Side:

```
@Path("/xml")

public class Service {

// List of video objects
private ArrayList<Video> videolist; 
//Parser object, parses xml  into video objects
private Parser parser = new Parser();


/*
 * Constructor
 * Parse XML and create video list on call
 */
public Service(){
    parser.createXML();
    videolist = parser.getList();       
}

/************************************************
 *GET
 * Path: /indexpath
 * list of all only <video> items
 * @return : ArrayList of Video objects
 ***********************************************/
@GET
@Path("/list")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public List<Video> getCustomerInXML() 
{ 
    return videolist;
}
}
```

Comment: Please include your web.xml. what is the host name your deploy this into? just replace localhost with that host name, and add the WAR name after as your servlet context name

Comment: Also getBaseURI implementation smells bad, try using `@Context URIIInfo info` (JAX-RS)

Comment: Just added my web.xml;  can I enter the host name as an IP? e.g 192.x.x.x/myfile.war

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The URL of a web app depends on many factors, the app server, configuration files, web.xml, and app server specific configuration.

But in *some* cases this is a "first thing to try if you don't know" (not an official, but "it works" rule of thumb)

```
http://hostnameOrIP:8080/WARFILENAMEWITHOUTEXTENSION
```

- **hostnameOrIP**: well, just replace with your host name or IP
- replace **8080** with the default port of your app server (9001, 9090, 3000 etc...)
- replace **WARFILENAMEWITHOUTEXTENSION** with, well, again, just war file name without extension

This is again an unofficial, try-it-first way if you have no other way to tell...

Comment: Thank you , after tinkering with my java version to make sure it matched that of  the environment my tomcat server is running on. I was to get it to work.